# Google api import cannot be resolved in Java [eclipse with gradle Plugin]

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, google-api-java-client

6 months ago i programmed a small tool that reads out a Google Sheet and creates an entrylist (for a Videogame) based on this Data. During this time, i installed a new clean version of windows and now i want  import this workspace to do some tweaks. The Problem is, im not able to get this programm working again.

In the Build.gradle there this error:

```
"Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle installation 'C:\Users\nikbr\Documents\Liga\gradle-7.0'.
Build file 'C:\Users\nikbr\Documents\ACC-Tools\ACC-Database\build.gradle' line: 14
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ACC-Database'.
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.4] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."
```

Its somehow related to the google api but i cant find any tutorial/help for this one. I think this is also the reason why im getting this error "The import com.google cannot be resolved".

My java-school skills are coming to an end at this point.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is go to

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java

and update the existing build.gradle in your project with the one they supply, and then in your main java file copy what they put in SheetsQuickstart.java
It will either work or at least give you easier compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else comes across this - the way I fixed this up (after following  Google Sheets quickstart https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java - and losing half a day) - was to not use the latest version of Gradle.

Using version 6.3 works (using NetBeans and the Tools > options > Java > Gradle > Use standard gradle version.